# TypeScript define external class

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Currently my code looks like this:

```
module Nexus {

    export class Scraper {

        private summonerName: string;

        private apiKey: string = '';

        private summonerStatsUrl = '';

        constructor(name: string) {

            this.summonerName = name;
        }

        getSeasonRank(): string {

            return 'aa';
        }

        getRankedStats(): string {

            return 'aa';
        }

        getSummonerStats(callback: Function) {

            var summonerStats = request(this.summonerStatsUrl + this.apiKey, function (error, body, response) {

                callback(response);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

And **app.ts**:

```
///<reference path="./Nexus.ts"/>

var colors = require('colors'),
    request = require('request'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    readline = require('readline'),
    rl = readline.createInterface({

        input: process.stdin,
        output: process.stdout
    });

rl.question('Insert summoner name: \r\n >> ', function (answer) {

    var scraper = new Nexus.Scraper(answer);

    scraper.getSummonerStats(function (result) {

        console.log(result);
    });
});
```

When I reach the new `Nexus.Scraper()`, I'm getting this error:

**Nexus is not defined**

While it should be since I'm including it? The module is named **Nexus** and I'm exporting the Scraper class. (The file is called **Nexus.ts**.)

Comment: It is recomended that a module name should start with a lowercase letter. And what is "///<reference path="./Nexus.ts"/>" ? Is Nexus a class ? The name of the typescript file should be same as name of class. And your app.ts should be inside the same module i.e. nexus. Then it will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your module looks as follows:

```
module Nexus {
    export class Scraper {
        private summonerName: string;
        private apiKey: string = '';
        private summonerStatsUrl = '';

        constructor(name: string) {

            this.summonerName = name;
        }
        
        getSeasonRank(): string {

            return 'aa';
        }
        
        getRankedStats(): string {
            return 'aa';
        }
        
        getSummonerStats(callback: Function) {
            var summonerStats = request(this.summonerStatsUrl + this.apiKey, function (error, body, response) {
                callback(response);
            });
        }
    }
}

export = Nexus;
```

Then, rather than using `/// <reference />` do this:

```
import Nexus = require('Nexus');
```

Answer (score 1):

You also need to export the module

```
export module Nexus {
    ...
}
```

then in your app.ts you can call it like:

```
import Nexus = require('./Nexus.ts');
```

Comment: 'Cannot find name Nexus' on app.ts

Comment: You will also need to require it on app.ts, if I am not mistaken.